# Ask question validation message improvement

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

When entering a new question if there are empty fields a pop up dialog appears. The pop up box's title is 'error'. I'm not sure this is an error really, sounds a bit harsh.

Also if multiple fields are empty then the pop up only mentions the first. As per the web I think this would be better if it listed all empty fields.

Comment: Your suggestion is right